# How to automatically open terminal window when I click a script?

Tags: terminal, file-opening, dolphin

My Python script has an interpreter in a first line. The file is executable. Is it possible that I click on my script and the terminal windows opens, executes the script and stays open?

Right now, when I click on it, a question pops up saying 'open or execute'. I choose execute, but nothing happens.

I use Kubuntu 16.10 and Dolphin file manager.

Answer (score 1):

In Dolphin, just right-click the script and choose "Open With > Other..." and hit the checkbox that says "Run in terminal". You'll need to choose your terminal emulator from the list of software as well. Unfortunately, I think you'll have to tell it to always open .py files the same way if you want it to stick.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. When I do this, konsole opens and throws `kf5.kcoreaddons.kaboutdata: Could not initialize the equivalent properties of Q*Application: no instance (yet) existing.` Next time when I click on the script, message pops up again saying `Open, execute, cancel`. If I click 'execute' nothing happens, no window opens